# How to keep the url hash when adding pagination to an ember.js web app

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a simple web app with a table that shows an array of users. The html for this is a basic table showing username / etc

The jsfiddle is here (though when you click the links to paginate jsfiddle seems to reload the page -not what I get locally when I copy/paste the below). But either way it helps show the basic app in action http://jsfiddle.net/Jmj4F/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div id="main">
    {{ outlet }}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
<table width="250px">                                                                            
<thead>
<th>id</th>
<th>username</th>
<th>update</th>
<th>delete</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
   {{#each person in controller}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{person.id}}</td>
      <td>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.username"}}</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="update" {{action updatePerson person}}/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="delete" {{action removePerson person}}/></td>
    </tr>
   {{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="pages">
  Page.
  <a href="/#/page/2">2</a>
  <a href="/#/page/3">3</a>
</div>
</script>
```

​
My app currently has 2 routes -one that pushes the default view with every user. The second is a simple page route that should slice the array and only show a subset of the users (basic pagination)

```
PersonApp = Ember.Application.create({});

PersonApp.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});

PersonApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});

PersonApp.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'person',
  addPerson: function(event) {
    var username = event.context.username;
    if (username) {
      this.get('controller.target').send('addPerson', username);
      event.context.set('username', '');
    }
  }
});

PersonApp.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  username: null
});

PersonApp.PersonController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: [],
  page: function(page) {
    //in a real app use the page # to slice the array
    var newContent = this.content.slice(1,2);
    this.set('content', newContent);
  }
});

PersonApp.Router = Ember.Router.create({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      connectOutlets: function(router) {
        var first = PersonApp.Person.create({ username: "first" });
        var middle = PersonApp.Person.create({ username: "middle" });
        var last = PersonApp.Person.create({ username: "last" });
        var people = [first,middle,last];
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('person', people);
      }
    }),
    page: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/page/:number',
      deserialize : function (router, params) {
        var pageNumber = params.number;
        router.get('personController').page(pageNumber);
      }
    })
  })
});

$(function () {
  PersonApp.initialize(PersonApp.Router);
});
```

​
Currently when I click the 2 I see the hash in the url changes from

```
http://localhost:8000/#/page/2
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/#/page/undefined
```

This example is still very hello world so I'm open to any improvements here. I'd like to use the router based approach just because it has back button support and that's a plus

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I finally have a fully paginated / filter / sortable array controller ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tScUj/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add a serialize method -now I get the page # instead of undefined

```
serialize: function(router, context) {
        return {
          number: context.get('number')                                                          
        }
      }
```

The only problem with adding this is that context is undefined so I get the following error. What should this method look like?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Comment: Your serialize() method looks correct. You probably just need to provide a context when transitioning to the route.

Comment: @DanGebhardt could you elaborate on this comment? should I add this in the router itself or some other place in the mvc chain?

Comment: this got me going down the right path -for anyone who might follow checkout my jsfiddle above for a complete filter/sort/pagination array controller example